# What does it mean to delegate to File Owner in my xib file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, interface-builder

I believe that `UIView` objects can delegate control to views in iOS programming. However, I thought this was already handled by an `IBAction` associated with an `IBOutlet` corresponding to the `UIView`.

In that case, what does it mean to drag a blue line (while pressing Ctrl) from the delegate circle of the `UIView` in my xib to File Owner?

Isn't the `UIView` already delegating to my view controller via an `IBAction`? The code seems to work if I don't specify anything for my `UIView`'s delegate.

Comment: Do you mean `IBAction` rather than `UIAction`?

Comment: What concrete subclass of `UIView` do you mean? `UIView` does not have a delegate, nor does it have any `IBOutlets` or `IBActions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Isn't the `UIView` already delegating to my view controller via an `IBAction`? The code seems to work if I don't specify anything for my `UIView`'s delegate".

It looks like you're confusing the idea of the [Target-Action Mechanism](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW14) with delegation. While you could in a way think of target-action as involving “delegation”, it would only be in the most general sense of the word in that it’s the target (generally a controller) that handles and implements the action (the message). However, a Cocoa programmer would probably refrain from explaining the target-action mechanism by using that particular word – delegation – as it would be too easy to confuse it with actual [Delegation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18).

When you “wire up” buttons and controls in the nib file to call `IBAction` methods in your controller object, that’s just the target-action mechanism at work. As you saw, the code works even if you "don't specify anything for my `UIView` delegate”, since target-action doesn’t involve delegation (in the Cocoa-sense of the word).

Delegation is generally used as an easier alternative to using subclassing to implement the desired behavior. For example, instead of having to create your own custom subclass of `UITableView` in order to have it know what data you want it to display, you can simply use the plain `UITableView` class, set its `delegate` to a controller class, and have the controller class implement the required/desired designated delegate methods. Using subclassing to accomplish that could potentially get complicated, since when you subclass, you need to have a full understanding of the inheritance chain and how all of the superclasses work.

Answer (score 1):

File's Owner is just a fancy way of disguising the name of the class that the XIB is taking it's references from.  When you drag the delegate outlet to your class, it's the equivalent of this line:

```
[self.myControl setDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you drag while pressing CNTRL from an IBOutlet or IBAction to a UILabel, UIButton or something else, you are binding events or outlets to your controller.

A delegate sort of a controller that must implement specific functions depending on which type of delegate it is. For example, the UIViewController, which implements the UIViewDelegate protocol, can implement

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad
```

the YourApplicationDelegate, which implements UIApplicationDelegate must implement

```
    -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

So a delegate is just a set of functions which define the behavior of an object, the classes that implement them can change this behavior.